# PHP error "Failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, joomla-extensions

I am not a programmer unfortunately, and I was extensively browsing to find a solution to my problem - without success. I hope you might help me.
I want to create a webpage locally using Windows, Joomla4, XAMPP & PHP8. The installation worked fine and I installed a component to add content (JoomShaper SP PageBuilder Lite, SPPB). However, an article that includes SPPB-content cannot be displayed. This is the error from Apache Error Log:

require_once(E:\xampp\htdocs\components\com_sppagebuilder\parser./../helpers/helper.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\xampp\htdocs\components\com_sppagebuilder\parser\addon-parser.php on line 20, referer: http://localhost/administrator/index.php?option=com_menus&view=items&menutype=mainmenu

I tried the following without success so far:

1. changing access rights of the helper.php and addon-parser.php files and all parent directories to 775
2. include `ini_set('include_path', '.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR');` in the helper.php

I do not know what else to do or where the problem is located then.

Thanks for any help, greatly appreciated!
Bernd

Comment: In the path it says it can't open, there appears to be an additional dot, `com_sppagebuilder\parser./../helpers` - `parser.`, whereas the "in" part of the message suggests the folder is named just `parser`. Having a `.` in your `include_path` should not cause this, I think, when a relative path that tries to go up a level is used, but I am not totally sure about that. (And removing it might break other parts of the application, that rely on it.) Can you check addon-parser.php, line 20, what the statement used there actually looks like?

Comment: Line 20 in addon-parser.php: `require_once __DIR__ . './../helpers/helper.php';`

Comment: Yes, I removed the first `.` and it is now being displayed! Thanks a lot @Cbroe